# App Dock moved inadvertently

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

Basic Android Samsung Galaxy 4 on ATT
No special launchers
Not rooted.
Just a normal out of the box Samsung 4.
Somehow I have moved the 'app dock' to the middle of the screen.
Tried long pressing the 'apps' button to drag it back to the bottom, but you cannot long press the apps button.
Tried long pressing the other buttons and it looks like I'm able to drag them to the dock at the bottom, but when I release, they snap back to where they were to start.

Comment: Reboot in safe mode if available.

Comment: Did you unlock your home screen?

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot and posted the link?